# How can i retrieve my mlab data in sorted order?

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I went through the below link, but i didn't understood.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/

any practical example?

Comment: hey @Avinash, can you specify whats unclear? Is it how the sort works/sorting documents by field?

Comment: @Avinash: If it is the connection part that is not clear to you: [This link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/) has  examples of using MongoDB Node drivers to connect to certain url, just set the url to your mlab url. Once you get hold of 'db', you can then do a `find` and a `sort`.